# Зачем нужна роль spinbutton?

Tags: html

Вроде искал везде, но полное описание не смог найти. Что означает роль `spinbutton`? Для чего она нужна?

```html
<input
  id="myInput"
  type="text"
  role="spinbutton" // ???
  autocomplete="off"
/>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input нет такого атрибута. Так что спрашивайте у того, кто его написал

Comment: @ArchDemon, какой атрибут ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy, атрибут role у элемента input. В спецификации html его нет, а значит либо автор неправильно указал теги вопроса, либо это специфичный атрибут автора, который его вписал с какой-то целью

Comment: @ArchDemon, ты смотришь атрибуты специфичные для `input` - `role` - это один из глобальных атрибутов. Для примера, по твоей ссылке отсутствует атрибут `id`, по твоей логике - такого атрибута тоже нет :)

Comment: @Grundy, действительно, отстал от жизни. Тогда вот эта ссылка https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#index-aria-spinbutton

Comment: @ArchDemon, лучше вот эта: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#spinbutton где сразу описание идет

Answer (score 0):

`role="spinbutton"` - поле для ввода числа. Эквивалент в HTML — `<input type="number">`.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#spinbutton
- https://doka.guide/a11y/aria-roles/